# BEM: How to (and should I) reuse class names?

Tags: css, bem

Lets suppose I have the following site structure:

[image: Site structure]

---

As you can see, the `affirmation` blocks serve the same purpose, so it makes sense to use the same name for them, but it creates a name conflict.

---

**The question is the following:**

- Is there a cool trick that allows me to reuse class names without creating conflicts?
- If there is, is it a good idea? **Is it BEM-like?**
- Is it better just to come up with a new class name (something like `affirmation-awesome`?

---

***Note:***

I use `affirmation__p` instead of `cool-block__p` and `awesome-block__p` because that text must be styled differently.

Comment: What do you mean by a **name conflict**?

Comment: @VinaySharma : Basically, I can't style `.affirmation__p` properly, adhering to BEM conventions anymore. (there are two different `affirmation__p`s and they must be styled differently) Or can I? Maybe SCSS nesting? (if it works the way I think it does)

Answer (score 0):

Using BEM conventions, these two blocks do not conflict when using BEM conventions correctly. Typically when nesting you should not really venture into to many nesting layers layers but using SCSS they can be split up assuming they are blocks with separate styling conventions. Think of BEM as grouping and structuring your code in an orderly fashion, but do not go beyond 3 nesting layers as this can make your code messy & unreadable.

```
.cool-block{
    background:#f5f5f5;
    padding:1rem;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    &__affirmation{
        background: #ffffff;
        color: #333;

        &__p{
            font-size: 1.2rem;
            }
        }
    }
```

and your html:

```
        <div class="cool-block">
            <div class="cool-block__affirmation">
                <div class="cool-block__affirmation__p">
                    This is my cool block
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Then for your other block you can separate:

```
.awesome-block{
    background:#e7e7e7;
    padding:2rem;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    &__affirmation{
        background: #333333;
        color: #ffffff;

        &__p{
            font-size: 1.4rem;
            }
        }
    }
```

and your html for this:

```
       <div class="awesome-block">
            <div class="awesome-block__affirmation">
                <div class="awesome-block__affirmation__p">
                    This is my awesome block
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I thought we were not supposed to be using `__` more than once 